# How to add interrupted time series in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Since I am just a python beginner I hope, that I bother you not too much with my question. I'd like to plot only parts of a time series from a dataset such as this:

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=np.arange(10)
b=np.arange(100, 105)
c=np.arange(30, 40)
d=np.arange(55, 60)
e=np.append(a,b)
f=np.append(c,d)
plt.plot(e,f)
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Then I get a plot with a long diagonal line between the data series. What to do to get rid of that, in other words I want that the x-axis only shows 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100,101,102,103,104 and the corresponding y-values and nothing in between. Moreover if I have a very long time series (e.g. from an oscilloscope measurement), is it possible to show up that some patterns are repeated with e.g. big dots in the middle of the plot? I've tried to convert the x data into a string and several other things, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on this part of your question:

> Then I get a plot with a long diagonal line between the data series. What to do to get rid of that [...]

It sounds that a scatteplot should meet your needs, so try this:

Add this to your code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(e, f)

for i, txt in enumerate(e):
    ax.annotate(txt, (e[i],f[i]))

fig.show()
```

To get this plot:

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish with this part:

> Moreover if I have a very long time series (e.g. from an oscilloscope
>   measurement)

Anyway, I hope my suggestion at least fixes the main part of your problem.

Comment: @Wachauer If my answer was not what you were looking for, I (or someone else) may still be able to help you if you are willing to share some feedback.